# Programmatically detect Samsung KNOX supported devices

Tags: android, samsung-knox

I have an app that runs on all android devices.

I have specific functionality that work only for Samsung KNOX supported devices.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically  detect if a device is a Samsung Knox supported device

Thank

Comment: Hei. Did you find any solutions?